# Как растянуть блок по ширине?

Tags: html, css

Я правильно понимаю, что этот код растянет `div` по ширине от `255px` до правого края?

```
left:255px;
right:0;
```

Но он почему-то не работает. Что делать?

Comment: position:absolute или fixed надо указать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Забыли `position: absolute` указать:

```css
.div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 255px;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
    background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div
```

Comment: @Air вопрос прочитай. Это требование.

Comment: @Air "код растянет div по ширине от 255px до правого края"

Comment: Всмысле не к селу не к городу, а как по вашему растянуть?

Comment: @Duoxx, я не прав...  Признаю...   Я и забыл, что и так можно...

Comment: sair, поменял цвет блока, что бы свой минус свой убрать...)))

Answer (score 2):

Сделаем правильно, согласно посту:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 255px;
}
```